# MySQL slow connection on some computers

Tags: mysql

I have the following situation:

Computer with IP 192.9.200.229:

```
$>  time mysql -h192.9.200.19 -u<user> -p<pass> <db> -e 'select * from <table> limit 10'
real    0m0.010s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.007s
```

Computer with IP 192.9.200.242:

```
$> time mysql -h192.9.200.19 -u<user> -p<pass> <db> -e 'select * from <table> limit 10'

real    0m4.869s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
```

I really don't want to disable the name resolution (i.e. `skip-name-resolve`) on the server (which solved the timing issue), because it messed with all the other systems connecting to this DB.

Also, I may add that the server has a Windows OS and is connected to 2 networks.

Does anyone have a solution to this connection problem?